# Efficient SQL procedure to get data from name value pair table into DataSet?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, entity-attribute-value

Using SQL Server, have a name value pair table. Each row is basically userid, contentid, sectionid, parameter, value. So there is data I want to display in a table such as user information. Each bit of information is in it's own row, sow how do I get it into a DataSet for use in a Repeater? Can I somehow merge the rows into one? So I can get multiple parameter/value pairs on one row?

so like...

two rows for user 32:

```
(param / value)
fname / Bob
lname / Smith
```

displayed on one row in a repeater like this:

```
Bob Smith
```

Any ideas? Oh yeah and the reason it is in the name/value pair format is to adhere to a required standard.

Comment: The more common name for this design is Entity-Attribute-Value, or EAV.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like...

```
SELECT fff.firstname, lll.lastname
FROM (
  SELECT ff.value AS firstname
  FROM PairTable AS ff
  WHERE ff.param = 'fname'
    AND ff.userId = 32
) fff, (
  SELECT ll.value AS lastname
  FROM PairTable AS ll
  WHERE ll.param = 'lname'
    AND ll.userId = 32
) lll
```

Comment: This is simpler than PIVOT though, +1

Answer (score 0):

Sucky standard....  :)

Anyway, your best bet is to play some magic (cursor) with your stored proc and return the data from the stored procedure in the format you want.  Then binding to a DataSet, or a string list, is trivial.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is [PIVOT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410.aspx).

Something like this (untested because I have no SQL Server around now)

```
SELECT UserID, [fname] AS firstname, [lname] AS lastname
FROM 
(SELECT UserID, value, name from PairTable WHERE UserID=32 ) p
PIVOT
(
value
FOR name IN
( [fname], [lname] )
) AS pvt
```

Answer (score 0):

That table is awful.  No offense ;-)

Relational databases just doen't do EAV tables very well.

You can also group, and do conditional CASE statements - like this:

```
SELECT   UserID,
         MAX(CASE WHEN param = 'fname' THEN value ELSE '' END) AS fname,
         MAX(CASE WHEN param = 'lname' THEN value ELSE '' END) AS lname
FROM     MyEAVTable
GROUP BY UserID
```

The PIVOT syntax is great - the only benefit to this solution is that it will work with SQL 2000 as well.